# How to store fit, lower and upper confidence intervals in another data frame in R using predict()

Tags: r, regression, prediction, predict

I created a linear regression model (linear_model) in R using the lm() function. I have a separate data frame (ObservedData) with a lot of collected data on the x variable and I need to predict the y variable using the linear model. I need to store the fit, lower and upper confidence intervals in this ObservedData data frame rather than creating a different data frame with the predicted results because each row in the ObservedData data frame has other attribute data that I need to retain in relation to the predicted y.

To do this, I used the following code:

`ObservedData$predicted_y <- predict(linear_model, newdata = ObservedData, interval = 'confidence')`

This works, but it is storing the fit, lwr, and upr values oddly in the ObservedData data frame. The column names it creates are: predicted_y[,"fit"], predicted_y[,"lwr"], and predicted_y[,"upr"] and I can't call on any one of these columns specifically because R only recognizes one column, ObservedData$predicted_y, which seems to be all three of these columns linked together in some way. How do I use the predict function to create three columns with the fit, lower and upper confidence intervals within the ObservedData data frame so that I can call on each column independently?

Answer (score 1):

if we transform the data.frame into a tibble as in `dplyr::tibble(ObservedData)`, we can have the predicted_y information in a list column, it makes things easier to access:

```
mod <- lm(data = iris, Sepal.Length ~ .)
iris |> 
    tibble() |> 
    mutate(predicted_y = predict(mod, newdata = iris, interval = "confidence")) |> 
    pull(predicted_y) |> 
    head()

       fit      lwr      upr
1 5.004788 4.916254 5.093323
2 4.756844 4.647837 4.865850
3 4.773097 4.680386 4.865808
4 4.889357 4.787841 4.990872
5 5.054377 4.960750 5.148004
6 5.388886 5.278348 5.499423
```

predicted_y is stored as a matrix, which can be further subsetted as appropriate:

```
iris2 <- iris |> 
    tibble() |> 
    mutate(predicted_y = predict(mod, newdata = iris, interval = "confidence"))

iris2$predicted_y[,"lwr"] |>
    head()

       1        2        3        4        5        6 
4.916254 4.647837 4.680386 4.787841 4.960750 5.278348
```

Answer (score 1):

From the help page [`help("predict.lm")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.lm.html), section Value, my emphasis.

> `predict.lm` produces a vector of predictions or a **matrix** of predictions and bounds with column names `fit`, `lwr`, and `upr` if interval is set.

This means that the new column `predicted_y` is a matrix column, see the first `str()` call.
You have to `cbind` all but that column with the matrix `predicted_y`. Since the original `ObservedData` is a data.frame, the `cbind` method called is `cbind.data.frame` and the result is the wanted one.

```r
ObservedData <- mtcars[c("mpg", "hp")]

linear_model <- lm(mpg ~ hp, ObservedData)
ObservedData$predicted_y <- predict(linear_model, newdata = ObservedData, interval = 'confidence')

str(ObservedData)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ mpg        : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ hp         : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ predicted_y: num [1:32, 1:3] 22.6 22.6 23.8 22.6 18.2 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "fit" "lwr" "upr"

nc <- ncol(ObservedData)
ObservedData <- cbind(ObservedData[-nc], ObservedData[[nc]])

str(ObservedData)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ hp : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ fit: num  22.6 22.6 23.8 22.6 18.2 ...
#>  $ lwr: num  21 21 22 21 16.6 ...
#>  $ upr: num  24.2 24.2 25.5 24.2 19.7 ...
head(ObservedData)
#>                    mpg  hp      fit      lwr      upr
#> Mazda RX4         21.0 110 22.59375 21.00634 24.18116
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0 110 22.59375 21.00634 24.18116
#> Datsun 710        22.8  93 23.75363 21.97149 25.53578
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 110 22.59375 21.00634 24.18116
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7 175 18.15891 16.64651 19.67131
#> Valiant           18.1 105 22.93489 21.29561 24.57417
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This will fail if there is missing data in `lm`, use `merge` instead of `cbind`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```r
library(broom)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars)
aa <- augment(fit, interval = "confidence")
names(aa)
names(aa)
 [1] ".rownames"  "mpg"        "cyl"        "disp"       "hp"        
 [6] "drat"       "wt"         "qsec"       "vs"         "am"        
[11] "gear"       "carb"       ".fitted"    ".lower"     ".upper"    
[16] ".resid"     ".hat"       ".sigma"     ".cooksd"    ".std.resid"
```

In tidyverse you could use `|> dplyr::select(c(names(mtcars), ".fitted", ".lower", ".upper"))`

to discard all the unwanted stuff about residuals etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `mtcars` data frame that comes with R.

```
head(mtcars, 3)
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Let's fit some model,

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars)
```

next use `predict`.

```
prd <- predict(fit, se.fit=TRUE, interval='confidence')
```

Finally we `merge` the predictioons to the data.

```
mtcars <- merge(mtcars, predict(fit, se.fit=TRUE, interval='confidence')$fit, 
                by=0, sort=FALSE)
```

We do not use `cbind` here, because if observations are deleted in `lm` because of missing data, we would get an error `arguments imply a different number of rows`.

#### Gives:

```
head(mtcars, 3)
#       Row.names  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb      fit      lwr      upr
# 1     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 22.59951 19.56821 25.63080
# 2 Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 22.11189 19.14278 25.08099
# 3    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 26.25064 23.55729 28.94400
```

In one step:

```
mtcars |> lm(mpg ~ ., data=_) |> predict(se.fit=TRUE, interval='confidence') |> 
  base::`$`(fit) |> merge(mtcars, by=0, sort=FALSE)
#       Row.names      fit       lwr      upr  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1     Mazda RX4 22.59951 19.568211 25.63080 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 Mazda RX4 Wag 22.11189 19.142784 25.08099 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3    Datsun 710 26.25064 23.557289 28.94400 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```